# Clipboard.setString works in Android but not in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, clipboard

I'm using react 17 and `@react-native-clipboard/clipboard library` to copy text in clipboard.

`Clipboard.setString` method it works on Android but not in iOS.

Anyone have an idea of how can I fix this?

I have already tried to run `pod install`, resetting the cache, reopen the simulator etc.

Comment: any error or warning after triggering setString function?

Comment: there're no errors or warnings: on android after triggering the function I can paste the content. On iOS I can't.

Comment: I'm not using expo (I did expo-eject)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Clipboard` directly from React Native:

```
import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: not working, in addition is deprecated :(